# How to verify the email links in the selenium without login to mail?

Tags: selenium, testng

How to verify the email links in the selenium without login to mail?

I need to click the email link after my first test is completed and i should not login to gmail as i need to verify for dynamic mails. So is that possible to use any other option please help me on this. and we are using sql DB.

Comment: I remember your last post. Is the email link stored in the DB? If so, you can access it via a DB connector, like JDBC.

Comment: In db all the email content are saved as html tag. in that i need to find the email link. is that possible to find?

Comment: It could be. Could you provide an example of email content?

Comment: i am not able to add the sample mail content here.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help you very much if I don't see anything. But you can try retrieving the html as a String and split it to get the precious link.

Comment: Sure i will check it @Y-B Cause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [restmail.net](http://restmail.net), it has very clear REST API.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a real mail server use a fake one (e.g. [JTalks Pochta](https://github.com/jtalks-org/pochta)):

- Configure your app to point to such a server
- In your tests access fake server via REST to get the contents of the emails
- Parse out links from the body
- Profit

Comment: Will please provide any documents or links to know more about this. thanks in advance.